# If I replace files that are in use by a hung process and start a new process, will it use the new files or the old ones?

Tags: files, rhel, process, file-descriptors, hang

I am on Red hat GNU/linux 2.6.32-431.29.2.el6.x86_64.

Recently - One of my process hung. This process was using few files from a directory - say DIR-1 . 
While process was in hung state, I moved ( and not copied )  these files to a backup dir - say DIR-BKP and added newer version of the files to DIR-1 directory. Note these newer version of files have exactly same as the ones from DIR-BKP folder.

Since my process is still in hung state during all this, what will happen if I start a new process, which is going to use files from DIR-1 ? Will the new process use files from DIR-BKP or DIR-1 ? Since old process is still using older version of files ( albeit they are moved to DIR-BKP directory ) , not sure if the new process will use newer version of files or will keep using older version.

Answer (score 1):

If you copy files to a new location, then no process is going to be aware of that unless you change something to direct it to the new location (e.g. change a command line option or edit a config file somewhere). A process isn't going to automatically follow the files if you move them. So, the new process should attempt to use the files from DIR-1.

A couple of questions though:

1. Why don't you just kill the hung process before starting a new one (possibly safer)?
2. Why didn't you just copy the files, rather than move, if the new ones are exactly the same?

Comment: Why don't you just kill the hung process before starting a new one (possibly safer)? - Actually, I did not notice hung process during deployment, I deployed newer version of files and realized after couple of days that there is hung process. So - ideally - yes, I should have killed the hung process but did not .

Comment: Thanks for valuable input. I was also having same impression but was willing to confirm. There was a doubt in my mind - whether kernel uses file handle from already hung process or look for a new file handle when a new process is started.

Comment: No problem. In general, processes locate files based on their path in the filesystem. If you change the path to a file, then you would usually have to tell that to the process somehow. Unless it has some clever way of searching the filesystem for a particular file (which is rare).